# Floyd-Warshall Algorithm - Why this order?

Tags: algorithm, loops

In the algorithm, you have 3 loops for shortest[u,v,x] which goes
x from 1 - n,
u from 1 - n,
v from 1 - n.

Why are the loops from x,u,v and not x,v,u or u,v,x?

Comment: Is there some reason to think that a different order might be better?

Comment: Just trying to understand the logic. :(

Comment: I learned it with `k, i, j`. Ultimately it doesn't matter, as long as you understand the logic and change your formulas accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `(u,v)` are indices for vertices and `x` denotes the index such that we are finding the shortest distance between vertex `u` and vertex `v` with only those vertices in between that are numbered `<= x`.

Hence the recurrence for `dist[u,v,x]` uses `dist[u,v,x-1]`, `dist[u,x,x-1]` and `dist[x,v,x-1]`.

Since there are three vertices involved (`u,v,x`) in the computation of `dist[u,v,x]`, so we should have already computed `dist`'s for all three pairs before computing `dist[u,v,x]`.

So, the loop for `x` has to be the outer-most loop. Inner loop can be either `v,u` or `u,v` because both are vertices.